# How to share mobile internet with a friend and keep noroot firewall running?

Tags: firewall

Friend's smartphone can only access internet if I stop "noroot firewall" app, while he is connected thru wifi hotspot here.

While it is running, no log is shown to friend's blocked accesses.

What I need to configure to let it work? 
If not possible, is there another alternatve?

I tried seting, at my friend's phone as fixed ip, dns etc like this:
Dns 4.2.2.2 and 8.8.8.8
Gateway 192.168.1.0 or my cell ip.
Netmask 255.255.0.0 or 255.0.0.0
But did not work either.

Comment: @beeshyams accordind to this answer's comments https://android.stackexchange.com/a/74621/172167, dns 4.2.2.2 and 8.8.8.8 should have worked with noroot firewall. May be i need to config more things here for the static ip address to let it work. Will add screenshot.